# Time complexity (in big-O notation) of the following recursive code?

Tags: recursion, big-o, time-complexity

What is the  `Big-O` time complexity ( `O` ) of the following recursive code?

```
public static int abc(int n) {
    if (n <= 2) {
        return n;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = 1; j < n; j *= 2) {
        sum += j;
    }
    for (int k = n; k > 1; k /= 2) {
        sum += k;
    }
    return abc(n - 1) + sum;
}
```

My answer is `O(n log(n))`.  Is it correct?

Comment: How did you get O(n)?

Comment: Hi there. I made a mistake. My answer is O(nlogn)

Comment: How did you get O(n log n)?

Comment: I am not sure if I am correct but.
Based on my understanding, each call for a recursive method is O(1).
If there are n calls to be made, it will be O(n).
Based on the code fragment, n log n calls are made.
Therefore it will result in a time complexity of O(nlogn).

Answer (score 2):

Where I'm sitting...I think the runtime is **O(n log n)**.  Here's why.

- You are making *n* calls to the function.  The function definitely depends on *n* for the number of times the following two operations are made:

  - You loop up to 2*log(n) values to increment a sum.

For a worst case, *n* is extremely large, but the overall runtime doesn't change.  A best case would be that *n* <= 2, such that only one operation is done (the looping would not occur).